# sqlite and smiley android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a new query to be solved. i was able to display selected smiley in edittext and when i submit it is displayed in Textview.

question 1: same in list view is it possible instead of textview

question 2: i need to display specialcharcter of the selected (smiley from gridview) and display that specialcharcter from sqlite DB.

My sqlite DB consist of 3 fields,

1._ID(Primary key)
2.specialcharcter Text ----------(like :), :()
3.URL Text (Image smiley).

when i select the particular smiley from gridview how can i display corresponding specialcharcter from sqlite DB. Please help me in this sissue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Raghav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans1 : Yes It is. Refer API Demos List View. Find Listview with Icon and Button using ListView Adapter.

Ans2 : Rather than using Sqlite , You can achieve the same using Hashmap with (Id ,(SpclChar ,URL)). Put Image Buttons on Gridview. And OnClick you pass the Id to the hashmap. Try to avoid Sqlite DB , Until and unless you want to persist something.